# How to map an empty file using mmap

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, mmap

I am trying to create an empty file if it does not exists. And than map it using mmap() so, that i can pass it to my other program for writing. I am not sure which arguments for mmap are suitable for an empty file. My code works for non empty files but gives error "Invalid argument" if file is empty

Code program1 (only creates an empty file if not exists)

```
int i;
int fd = open("/home/sungmin/dummy_programs/dummy.txt", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0777);
char *pmap;
pid_t child;

if (fd == -1)
{
    perror("Error opening file for writing");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}        

struct stat fileInfo = {0};

if (fstat(fd, &fileInfo) == -1)
{
    perror("Error getting the file size");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/*if (fileInfo.st_size == 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: File is empty, nothing to do\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}*/

pmap = mmap(0, fileInfo.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC  , MAP_ANONYMOUS, fd, 0);
if (pmap == MAP_FAILED)
{
    close(fd);
    perror("Error mmapping the file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Calling fork function */
if((child=fork())==0){

printf("Iam Child process\n\n");
static char *argv[]={"This is some sample text. I need to write this text in my dummy file.","/home/sungmin/dummy_programs/dummy.txt",NULL};
execv("/home/sungmin/dummy_programs/pro2",argv);
    exit(127); 
}
else { 
    printf("Iam parent, waiting for child process to exit\n\n");        
    waitpid(child,0,0); 
    printf("Existing parent\n\n");
}

/* Don't forget to free the mmapped memory*/
if (munmap(pmap, fileInfo.st_size) == -1)
{
    close(fd);
    perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Un-mmaping doesn't close the file, so we still need to do that.*/
close(fd);
```

Code program2 (opens same file as program1 and writes text passed by program1)

```
 size_t i;
int fd;
char *pmap;
pid_t child;
struct stat fileInfo = {0};
const char *text = argv[0];

fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0600);

if (fd == -1)
{
    perror("Error opening file for writing");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}  

size_t textsize = strlen(text) + 1; // + \0 null character

if (lseek(fd, textsize-1, SEEK_SET) == -1)
{
    close(fd);
    perror("Error calling lseek() to 'stretch' the file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (write(fd, "", 1) == -1)
{
    close(fd);
    perror("Error writing last byte of the file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

pmap = mmap(0, textsize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

if (pmap == MAP_FAILED)
{
    close(fd);
    perror("Error mmapping the file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Writting users text to file */
for (i = 0; i < textsize; i++)
{
    pmap[i] = text[i];  
}   

// Write it now to disk
if (msync(pmap, textsize, MS_SYNC) == -1)
{
    perror("Could not sync the file to disk");
}

/* Don't forget to free the mmapped memory*/
if (munmap(pmap, textsize) == -1)
{
    close(fd);
    perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Un-mmaping doesn't close the file, so we still need to do that.*/
close(fd);
```

Comment: `O_RDONLY`?! `O_APPEND`!? You open the file for **read only** appending the modifications always?! How about `O_RDWR`?

Comment: Also: `EINVAL (since Linux 2.6.12) length was 0.` Since it is empty, you cannot `mmap` it. It doesn't make any sense. One can only map a non-empty region.

Comment: You can't use `mmap()` to grow a file.  The size is fixed at the time the mapping is done.

Comment: Also, note that in `static char *argv[]={"str1…","/home/sungmin/dummy_programs/dummy.txt",NULL};
execv("/home/sungmin/dummy_programs/pro2",argv);` the humungous long `"str1…"` value is treated as `argv[0]` in the child process, not `argv[1]` as it looks as though you're expecting.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler actually in my other program iam growing the same file with mmap so that is not the problem.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I want my program 1 to open or create am empty file, and program 2 to write the text which iam passing from argv[].So please guide me for the parameters i should use in mmap?

Comment: Did you take this code from an example program using mmap to share memory between many programs started by fork()? The way you have the code here, there's no point doing the mmap in Program 1 because the exec call will overwrite all the memory mappings when it starts the new program.

Comment: And you can't use `MAP_ANONYMOUS` with a file descriptor. Anonymous and a file are opposite things that cannot be mixed.

Comment: @ZanLynx yes i took this example program. I am using mmap in program1 because once its written by program2 i want to read the modified file. Mmap will help me because i can access the memory location of the file even if it is extended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `truncate` to extend the file length after creating it before mapping it.

Yes, the function name sounds wrong, but `truncate` can actually set the file length to any number. Be sure to use a multiple of 4K for best results.

Then, if you want to keep the mapping open to see data between Program 1 and 2, you need to get rid of ANONYMOUS and map with MAP_SHARED in Program 1. A mapping that isn't shared will not show changes made by other programs. Or it might, if it has to reload from disk. It's weird, don't mix SHARED and not-SHARED mappings.

Once you've changed Program 1 to use `truncate`, take that `lseek` and `write` code out of Program 2. The file will already have been created and extended by Program 1.

Comment: just one thing to ask? Is my approach right of doing what i am trying to do? I mean, Program 1 creates an empty file if it does not exists, Program 2 than writes on same file. for moving between program 1 to program 2 iam using fork and exec and mmap for sharing same file? is the approach right or can be used in better way?

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan: I assume that you're doing this just for fun, or experimenting, because really, for this job you'd just have Unix shell tools.

Comment: I am not doing this for real fun i want to achieve something. Actually I want to send a font file from program 1 to program 2 than program 2 will convert that font file to an XML file and than i will read/ modify that XML file from my program 1. Thats why iam making this dummy functionality. So now please give your feedback?